# Клик по td элементу javascript

Tags: javascript, java, dom, click

Как кликнуть по td элементу?

```
document.getElementById('zz').click();
```

Не работает. Судя по всему по такому элементу кликнуть скриптом нельзя, есть костыль какой-то?

Гугл не помог

upd: Нужно инициировать клик по элементу, сайт открывается в WebView JavaFX.

upd2: если кликнуть в консоли браузера, возвращает undefined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d5aotfqx/  у меня всё работает

Comment: мне нужно кликнуть по нему, функция на сайте уже задана

Comment: Запустить мышинное событие щелчка c координатам td (середины) можно? `fireEvent(new MouseEvent(...))` в JavaFX? или в javascript `event.initMouseEvent(...)`?

Comment: @Sergey спасибо за наводку, сейчас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: @Sergey что-то до меня никак не дойдет, как координаты элемента получить..

Comment: Сам не знаю. Это самое сложной в такой методе. Должны быть какие-то функции, если не прямо, то косвенно можно попытаться вычислить. Надо смотреть руководства по js или javafx

Comment: Обычный click() должен работать: https://jsfiddle.net/37m57gqd/ К тому же с чего вы взяли, что в консоль в результате должно падать что-то другое, кроме undefined? Это типичное возвращаемой значение, если не задано другое.

Comment: @AlexKrass не знаю, можно ли размещать ли ссылки, но попробуйте кликнуть с помощью скрипта в консоли по одному из коэффициентов на сайте [https://live.fonbet.com/?locale=ru](https://live.fonbet.com/?locale=ru) . Попробовал по вашему способу, тоже ничего не выходит. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После двухдневных пыток гугла, чисто случайно нашел подсказку, которая мне помогла. 
По элементу удалось кликнуть выполнив две следующих строчки кода

```
browserEngine.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('event5808638win1').onmousedown();");
browserEngine.executeJavaScript("document.getElementById('event5808638win1').onmouseup();");
```

Comment: "Две следующих строчки кода". Не выдумывайте лишних терминов :)

Comment: @D-side спасибо :))

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что в отличие от простого вызова функции, у событий есть фазы всплытия или туннелирования(в данном случае только всплытия). Поэтому вызвать простое выполнение функции недостаточно, как это делается с помощью `click()`, т.к. на уровнях выше могут быть еще перехватчики.

Нашел такой ответ: http://darktalker.com/2010/07/manually-trigger-dom-event/

```
/**
 * trigger a DOM event via script
 * @param {Object,String} element a DOM node/node id
 * @param {String} event a given event to be fired - click,dblclick,mousedown,etc.
 */
var fireEvent = function(element, event) {
    var evt;
    var isString = function(it) {
        return typeof it == "string" || it instanceof String;
    }
    element = (isString(element)) ? document.getElementById(element) : element;
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        // dispatch for IE
        evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt)
    }
    else {
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

Этот код уже заставляет событие выполнится полноценно, вместе с фазой всплытия.

Пример:

```js
var fireEvent = function(element, event) {
    var evt;
    var isString = function(it) {
        return typeof it == "string" || it instanceof String;
    }
    element = (isString(element)) ? document.getElementById(element) : element;
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        // dispatch for IE
        evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt)
    }
    else {
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("red");
    });
    
    $("table").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("blue");
    });
    
    // Trigger the event.
    fireEvent($("td")[0], 'click');

});
```

```css
td{
  padding:30px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.red{
  background:red;
}
.blue{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
<tr> 
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но это немного не то, что мне было нужно! Решение уже нашел, еще раз спасибо

Answer (score -2):

Используй jquery:

```
 $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){
    alert("sdffsd");
  });
```

Comment: Мне нужно кликнуть по элементу, через WebView в Java. Я хочу написать бота, но кликнуть по тд элементу не могу.

Comment: Это следит за событиями, но не инициирует их.

Comment: @jessez укажите это в вопросе. Возможно, из Java/WebView это будет сделать даже проще.

Comment: @D-side указал, спасибо. Но сомневаюсь, что это будет действительно проще. Уже не первый день гуглю, ничего не нашел, что может помочь. Если в консоли браузера кликнуть, возвращает undefined